# Leer Json desde button html y presentarlo en un input

Tags: javascript, html

tengo este pequeño elemento html

```
<input type="text" name="f1t1" id="f1t1">
    <button title="Visualizar" text="Visualizar" type="button" onclick="visualizarCurso(' + JSON.stringify(' {'id': 6, 'fullname': 'prueba docente' } ' ) + '   )">
     Visualizar
     </button>

<script>
function visualizarCurso(item) {
    llenarModalCurso(item);
   }
    function llenarModalCurso(item) {
    var datos = JSON.parse(obj);
    $("#f1t1").val(datos.id);
    }
</script>
```

Porque no puedo acceder al id dentro d ese json y presentarlo en ese input
Nota: El json es mas grande solo presente 2 elementos de este para realizar la pregunta

Comment: Me parece que está mal formado el `string` del `onclick`. Abrí la consola del navegador(F12) y al apretar el botón te tiene que estar tirando errores.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tu tienes esto:

```
onclick="visualizarCurso(' + JSON.stringify('{'id': 6, 'fullname': 'prueba docente' }') + ')"
```

Tendrías que quitar el `' +` que está en el inicio y el `+ '` del final. También no van comillas simples `''` en el `JSON.stringify()`, aquí dentro va directo tu objeto. Debería ser así:

```
onclick="visualizarCurso(JSON.stringify({ 'id': 6, 'fullname': 'prueba docente'}))"
```

También estás intentando parsear algo que no existe:

```
var datos = JSON.parse(obj);
```

Debe ser el parámetro que recibe tu función:

```
var datos = JSON.parse(item);
```

---

Código:

```js
function visualizarCurso(item) {
  llenarModalCurso(item);
}

function llenarModalCurso(item) {
  var datos = JSON.parse(item);
  console.log(datos);
  $("#f1t1").val(datos.id);
}
```

```html
<input type="text" name="f1t1" id="f1t1">
<button title="Visualizar" text="Visualizar" type="button" onclick="visualizarCurso(JSON.stringify({ 'id': 6, 'fullname': 'prueba docente'}))">Visualizar</button>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.4.js"></script>
```